# Add-AzureCertificate not accepting shared path

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

As part of the deployment process am adding the certificates required for my cloud worker role.

**Add-AzureCertificate  -ServiceName "$service" -CertToDeploy "$certPath" -Password $CertPassword**

When the value for $certPath is a local path("**D:\certificates\cert.pfx**") am able to add the certificates and everything goes fine.

When the $certPath is a shared path ("**\shared.ad.abc.com\certificates\cert.pfx**"), am getting the below exception,

**"The given path's format is not supported"**

Please help me to get this solved!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get to know the command prompt command [net use](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true):

```
C:\Users\SomeUser>net use /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

And a simple sample:

```
net use z: \shared.ad.abc.com\certificates
```

Then in PowerShell use `z:\cert.pfx`